# Heroku Deploy React Error: Didn't get a result from child compiler ./src/App.css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

Looking to deploy a react app on Heroku but

```
            -----> Build
                   Running build
                   
                   > crmprototype@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_0b3e74dd_
                   > react-scripts build
                   
                   Creating an optimized production build...
                   Failed to compile.
                   
                   ./src/App.css
                   Error: Didn't get a result from child compiler
                       at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
                   
                   
            npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
            npm ERR! errno 1
            npm ERR! crmprototype@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
            npm ERR! Exit status 1
            npm ERR! 
            npm ERR! Failed at the crmprototype@0.1.0 build script.
            npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
            npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
            npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.gNVt2/_logs/2020-10-30T02_00_17_191Z-debug.log
```

Git repo is here

https://github.com/marcoantonio123456/wivo-testing

I can't seem to find what is wrong with my App.css file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your css file.  in the @font-face should be

`src: url(./fonts/Europa-Bold/Europa-Bold.woff);`

before you were pointing to `src: url(./fonts/Europa-Bold/Europa-Bold.css);`  which is not a font file, its a css file

Answer (score 1):

The import css file seems good to me, may it be because you committed the build folder and the .css file isn't there? there build folder shouldn't be committed.

Comment: Hi FLiotta, I tried deleting build and got the same error.